# How do you add a button to a html page that runs a serverside script?

Tags: php, html, shell-exec

What I have right now is

**HTML**

`<form action="test.php" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Run me now!">`

**php**

```
<?php
shell_exec('sh test.sh');
?>
```

**sh**

#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl restart cps.service

the sh file on its own does exactly what it is supposed to do, but when I try to click the button on my page that is supposed to run it nothing happens. all files are in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

I assume your code isn't working because functions like `shell_exec` are blocked by your php for obvious security reasons. Do you see any error? If not, add these lines on the top of your php page `test.php` to display errors

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If you are not seeing any PHP errors, may be its error from the terminal, echo the output of the `shell_exec` like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('test.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

If the problem was because it was disabled from `php.ini` enabled it by removing `shell_exec` from `disable_functions`

Comment: after adding the first few lines to the code the error log gave this out:  We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: Please refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448810/what-does-this-warning-mean-and-what-should-i-do-to-fix-it/448818

Comment: after adding "%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" to visudo it worked. however I dont want all files to not be password protected. any idea which files exactly I have to add there?

Answer (score 1):

the solution was adding "%www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart cps.service" to visudo